# Extended Euclidean Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

The question is as follows:

$3157x + 656y = 2173$.

I found so far

- $3157 = 4 \cdot  656 + 533$
- $656 = 1 \cdot  533 + 123$
- $533 = 4 \cdot  123 + 41$
- $123 = 3 \cdot  41 + 0$.

Now we do the reverse

- $41 = 1 \cdot  533 - 4 \cdot  123$
- $41 = 1 \cdot  533 - 4 \cdot  (1 \cdot  656 - 1 \cdot  533)$
- etc.
- $41 = 5 \cdot  3157 - 24 \cdot  656$

I'm just confused as to how I find $x$ and $y$ for $2173$ after this point.

Thank you everyone who helped me.

Comment: I think you went a step "too far".  Rather than express zero as a combination of 656 and 3157, we want a combination that gives their GCD, $3157a + 656b = 41$.  From there we only need to scale up to $2173 = 53*41$.

Comment: @coffeemath: I like your Answer and think it a worthwhile post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, you are writing your "reverse" step (called back substitution) with the wrong numbers. The first line, instead of reading $0 = 1 ⋅ 123$, which isn't true, it should read, $41 = (533⋅1) + (123⋅-4)$. You should be good from there.

Afterwards, you should arrive at the conclusion that:

$41 = (1 ⋅ 533) + (-4 ⋅ 123)$

$= (-4 ⋅ 656) + (5 ⋅ 533)$

$= (5 ⋅ 3157) + (-24 ⋅ 656)$

$= (-24 ⋅ 656) + (5 ⋅ 3157)$

This means that your answers for $x$ and $y$, are $5$ and $-24$ respectively for the last equation. Note: This is when everything is equal to $41$ not $2173$. You just need to multiply the last equation by $53$ in order to arrive at the final conclusion.

Comment: 41 = 5 * 3157 - 24 * 656 is the answer that I get for that solution. Where do I move from here?

Comment: I made an edit, for a complete solution.